# Problem with using Emotion with Gatsby.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby, emotion

I am following this tutorial of Gatsby about using Emotion. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/recipes/styling-css#using-emotion

I installed the Emotion using `npm install --save gatsby-plugin-emotion @emotion/core @emotion/styled` and set up my `gatsby-config.js` file like this

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [`gatsby-plugin-emotion`],
}
```

But when I was using it like the tutorial did, I encountered a problem where the inline-css of the component is `[object Object]`

My component looks like this

```js
import React from "react"
import { css } from "@emotion/core"

export default ({ children }) => (
  <main
    css={{
      backgroundColor: "red",
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </main>
)
```

and I tried to rewrite using a different approach

```js
import React from "react"
import { css } from "@emotion/core"

export default ({ children }) => (
  <main
    css={css`
      background-color: red;
    `}
  >
    {children}
  </main>
)
```

this time the inline-css of the component is a paragraph

```
You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. It isn't supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className` prop), but rather handed to emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value of `css` prop).
```

have no ideas why these two approach didn't work

Comment: I believe you don't need the second css: "css={`PUT CSS HERE`}

Comment: @Lowkase well it is just another(or recommended) way to write emotion in React. Go check out https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction you can see some examples of it

Comment: Do you have this at the top of your react component? ---->>>> 
/** @jsx jsx */

Comment: @Lowkase no I don't have it. Does it matter?

Comment: @Lowkase the jsx pragma isn't necessary here, `gatsby-plugin-emotion` should take care of the Babel plugin. Do you have a reproduction repo? Everything looks right in your question

Comment: is the styled component way working? (import styled from '@emotion/styled';) If yes then i guess the issue is related to @emotion/babel-preset-css-prop

Comment: @d3bgger yea you are right  the styled component way is working fine

Comment: @d3bgger after restart the dev server everything is working out fine. weird

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (without thorough understanding):

### Approach 01

Replace this:

```
import React from "react"
import { css } from "@emotion/core"
```

with this:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { css, jsx } from "@emotion/core"
```

### Approach 02

Update `gatsby-config.js` to contain the plugin `gatsby-plugin-emotion`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-emotion`,
  ],
}
```

This needs a restart of the gatsby development process.